# Wierd description text near HardOps Inserts

Tags: text-object, hard-ops

i think my issue isnt a issue and i think the solution is very easy, but i never worked with that "description thing". So the problem is, when I insert a HardOps insert via KitOps i get these strange description text next to an object. I hope you guys can help me out. I added screenshot to show the "strange description text".

I want only to hide this text or just to delelte it.

Thanks and have a nice day :)[image]

Comment: I guess that text is being produced by HardOps or KitOps. It certainly hasn't been produced by Blender itself so you'll have to ask the HardOps developer as that's a third-party addon not part of Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues related to add-ons not managed by Blender should be directed to support channels for that specific add-on. With that said, the answer is that all items with a representation in the 3D viewport (meshes, curves, empties, etc.) can have their name displayed by checking this box under Object Properties > Viewport Display. If you want to hide their name, just uncheck that box: [image].

Comment: Thank you. You saved my life :)